# "git branch" in git-bash shows "master" even after checkout tracking branch in git-gui

Tags: git

I have a problem with git-gui and git-bash in Windows.

1. Clone existing repository in git-gui
2. Branch->Checkout->Tracking Branch in git-gui
3. Go to my repo in git-bash
4. "git branch" in git-bash shows "master"

I was expecting to see my branch instead of "master". Any idea? What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in [git gui branch management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730760/git-gui-branch-management) , you need two steps in order to use a tracking branch.

Choosing a branch in "`Tracking Branch`" isn't enough.
You need to create it as well, and switch to it.

[image: add tracking branch]