# How do I switch branches in Git Gui?

Tags: git-branch, git-gui

I cant seem to figure out how to switch branches in Git Gui.

In Git Gui , I have cloned a repository from GitHub.  There are 2 branches: main and development.
I used the Branch > Create option to create and checkout 2 tracking branches: origin/main and origin/development.
Now I want to be able to switch between the 2 branches.  I thought that Branch > Checkout would let me do that.  But I end up with the message "You are no longer on a local branch.  If you wanted to be on a branch, create one now starting from 'This Detached Checkout'".  And my current branch says "HEAD".

All I want to do is be able to switch between my tracking branches.

How do I do this in Git Gui?  Please only answers for Git Gui, not command line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git gui branch management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4730760/git-gui-branch-management)

Comment: Flûte, I did not even check if there were duplicates... Voting for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to change branch (checkout) with git GUI:

1. Open the branch tab, click "checkout"

[image]

2. Click the branch you want to checkout:

[image]

---

Side note: You really should use the command line. This way you understand way better, in my opinion, what you are actualy doing, like, for example:

```
git checkout "mybranch"
```

Plus it's way faster, and git GUI, some might agree, sucks.